# How do I work around a "stack size specified is too small" error in Java on POWER8?

Tags: java, openjdk, cassandra, ppc64le, elasticsearch

I am trying to run Java applications (ElasticSearch and Cassandra) on Ubuntu (14.04) running on Power PC hardware using the OpenJDK.  I ran into an error:

```
The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 1664k  
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.  
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have found that the x86_64 OpenJDK java requires at least 160k for stack size.  So it appears the Power PC architecture requires a stack size ten times larger than x86_64.

Are there any other Java settings that are specific to Linux Java running on Power PC architecture?

Answer (score 1):

The way to change the stack size for running java on the command line is -Xss

In this case it is:  `java -Xss1664k JavaApplication`

If you are using Java applications that have configuration files (such as Cassandra or ElasticSearch) the stack size is often specified in the `JAVA_OPTS` variable of the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh`

Change `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss 1664k"` to `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss1792k"`

Try to start cassandra again. It will work.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22470628/1740715)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the `ppc64el` architecture other than `powerpc`. `Powerpc` is the 32 bits release, and and it is not recommend to run on POWER8 server.

On the other side, please use `ppc64el`, which is the 64-bits release and should have the stack size properly sized.